# Is JQuery a dev dependency or a dependency?

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, dependencies, installation

I wanna install *jquery* using npm, but I can't find any information out there about whether I should install it normally, or if I need to save it as a *devDependency* or a *dependency* as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely save it as a dependency.  Dev dependencies are dependencies that are only used during development and won't be bundled with the released product.  JQuery is a widely used library and will be used for the implementation of your project, so save it as a dependency.